# Qt does not find header file

Tags: c++, qt

I have such structure of files:

`├── MyProject/
│   ├── Include
│   │   ├── mainwindow.h
│   ├── Source
│   │   ├── main.cpp
│   │   ├── MyQtProjectFiles
│   │   │   ├── MyQtProject.pro`

MyQtProject.pro contains some strings:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD\..\..\Include
SOURCES +=  $$PWD\..\..\Source\main.cpp
HEADERS  += $$PWD\..\..\Include\mainwindow.h
```

But Qt produces the error : Cannot open include file: "mainwindow.h"; No such file or directory

Comment: It is my mistake of editing of question

Comment: I would just write "INCLUDEPATH += Include", "SOURCES +=  main.cpp", "HEADERS  += mainwindow.h"

Comment: But location of .pro file is Source/MyQtProjectFiles?

Comment: Why you are keeping `.pro` under `sources` ??

Comment: I think it is the part of source code

Comment: I got error - dependent "main.cpp" does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved, I deleted old cache files of previous build process. Recommended variable for usage in my case is _PRO_FILE_PWD_